# order of execution of statements in python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code that goes as

```
for x in name:
     print(x)
     os.system('exe file')#prints output1
     os.system('2nd exe file)#prints output2
```

it is printing

```
output1
x
output2
```

why is it happening?

Comment: Could one of your exe files be printing to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: could you add more code? where is the `name` defined an what's in it?

Answer (score 0):

This has been aswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731329/9067070). Check answers for ways to solve it.

> When you're outputting to a pipe, Python buffers your output that's
>   written to `sys.stdout` and outputs it after a flush, or after it's
>   overflown, or upon closing (when the program exits). While it'll
>   buffer the print calls, system calls output directly into stdout and
>   their output won't be buffered. That's why you're seeing such
>   precedence. To avoid that, use `python -u`:
>
> ```
> python -u test.py > test.out; cat test.out
> ```
>
> See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731329/9067070).
>
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731329/9067070):
>   [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

Comment: At your reputation level, you can't yet flag as duplicate. Until you can, please simply abstain from answering duplicates. Thanks.